# new Array() vs Object.create(Array.prototype)

Tags: javascript

A naive confusion:

```
var arr1 = new Array();
var arr2 = Object.create(Array.prototype);
//Inserting elements in "both arrays"
arr1[0] =0;
arr1[9] =9;
arr2[0] =0;
arr2[9] =9;
arr1.push(10);
arr2.push(10);
console.log(arr1.length); // prints 11
console.log(arr2.length); // prints 1
```

Both objects inherits Array.prototype, but they behave differently with the [] operator. Why?

Comment: Plain Objects don't calculate length for you like Arrays do...

Comment: What a horrible way to create an array!

Comment: Javascript Arrays created with Object.create are not real Arrays http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/ & http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2292-Extending-JavaScript-Arrays-While-Keeping-Native-Bracket-Notation-Functionality.htm

Comment: Pity the poor `var arr = []`.

Comment: it's actually hard to fake arrays and requires a slow getter using on-demand iteration for the length property...

Comment: Of course that var arr =[] is the proper way, but this has nothing to do with the question

Comment: Thanks Aamir for the link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first case you create an array object that maintains the `length` property when you access a integer, non-negative property (index).

In the second case you created a *regular object* that inherits the `Array` prototype. Using `[]` on that object is the same as any object and simply sets regular properties on it.

```
var arr1 = new Array(); // or var arr1 = [];
arr1[0] = 0;
arr1['foo'] = 3;
// arr1 has a length of 1 because 0 is an array index and 'foo' is a regular property.

var arr2 = Object.create(Array.prototype);
arr2[0] = 0;
arr2['foo'] = 3;
// arr2 has a length of 0 because both 0 and 'foo' are regular properties.
```

The ECMAScript 5 Language Spec describes how `length` is maintained in [section 15.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4).

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property
> names. A property name *P* (in the form of a String value) is an *array index* if and only if ToString(ToUint32(*P*)) is equal to *P* and
> ToUint32(*P*) is not equal to 2^(32−1).
>
> [...]
>
> Specifically, whenever a
> property is added whose name is an array index, the **length** property is
> changed, if necessary, to be one more than the numeric value of that
> array index;

Comment: Thanks Vache. I know about that, but in both cases, the objects created inherit from Array.prototype. As i noted in the example, the method push applied on the object created with Object.create, modifies the inherited property length. Meanwhile the notation with brackets behaves differently.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough in my answer. The bracket notation isn't a method that is part of the prototype, it's a way to access properties in Javascript. In an `Array` object (note that inheriting from `Array`'s prototype isn't enough to be an array) the brackets behave differently as it is explained in the spec. Now `push` and `length` are in the prototype and that's why calling `push` on the regular object maintains `length`.

Comment: Fully agree with your comment.

Answer (score -2):

`var arr1 = new Array();` is the proper way to instantiate an array. It is the same as using the array literal: `var arr1 = [];`

Comment: OP knows that. He's wondering why the "proper" and the "wrong" way behave differently.