# Array.isArray() returns false for array created with Object.create()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am facing a strange problem in Javascript. It may be due to lack of understanding from my side.

I have an array `a1`:

```
var a1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Then I add a new element to this array `a1`

```
a1['newEntry'] = 4
```

And then I create a new array `a2` using `a1`:

```
var a2 = Object.create(a1)
```

Then  `Array.isArray(a1)` returns `true`, but `Array.isArray(a2)` returns `false`. **What is happening here?** Could you please explain how this is happening?

Comment: `a1['newEntry']=4` this isn't adding any element to the array: you're just creating a property called `newEntry` with a value of `4`.

Comment: Well `Object.create` doesn't create arrays.

Comment: also related [new Array() vs Object.create(Array.prototype)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22022058/1048572)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

> The `Object.create()` method creates **a new object** with the specified prototype object and properties.

When you call `Object.create(a1)` **you're not creating a *real* array, you are creating an object which *looks like* an array**, but it's not. In fact, you could even try this:

```
> a1 instanceof Array
true
> a2 instanceof Array
true
```

and see that the result is `true` for both the variables.

Then what does `Array.isArray()` do? Well, it doesn't obviously use the `isinstanceof` statement. To be sure the variable is a *real* array, it [checks using the `Object.prototype.toString()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775722/check-if-object-is-array), like this:

```
> Object.prototype.toString.call(a1)
"[object Array]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(a2)
"[object Object]"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(a1) === "[object Array]"
true
> Object.prototype.toString.call(a2) === "[object Array]"
false
```

This is why calling `Array.isArray()` gives you these results: because it performs the above check. Now you are sure that, **even if `a2` *looks like* an array, *it is not* an array at all.**

---

Also, to clarify: when you do `a1['newEntry'] = 4` you're not adding a new element to the array. You are instead creating the property `newEntry` with value `4` on your existing array. To add an element to an array, you should use the `push()` method, like this:

```
> a1 = [1, 2, 3]
> a1.push(4)
> console.log(a1)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

Object.create() is creating an Object rather than an Array, thus when checking against Array.isArray(), it will return false.

Consider instead `Array.slice()`, e.g.

`var a2 = a1.slice(0);`

Source: [Clone Arrays with JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array)