# What Are Exotic Objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I just found out about [Exotic Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-exotic-object-internal-methods-and-slots) in ES6. I struggled a lot trying to understand them and couldn't find much simple information, so I have plenty questions:

1. Can I create new exotic objects types or only the ones defined by the standard can exist?
2. Which are the kinds of exotic objects defined by the standard?
3. Do we really need all the kinds of exotic objects, or are they there for compatibility with older standards? For instance, couldn't [Arguments exotic objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arguments-exotic-objects) be implemented with a normal array prefilled with the default arguments?
4. Initially, I imagined that `Object.create(proto)` didn't work as expected only on prototypes of exotic objects (e.g. [`Object.create(Array.prototype)` doesn't quite work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22022058/new-array-vs-object-createarray-prototype)), but then I realized that it also doesn't work as expected with the prototype of `Set` and `Map`, which don't seem to be exotic objects... are these some other kind of *special* objects different from exotic ones?
5. Is there any way to identify whether an object is an exotic one?

I'm quite confused about exotic objects; a generic overview on them would be much appreciated.

Comment: The linked specification appears to indicate that a bound function is an example of an exotic object.

Comment: "4.3.7 exotic object

object that does not have the default behaviour for one or more of the essential internal methods that must be supported by all objects

NOTE Any object that is not an ordinary object is an exotic object." So you can create new instances of such objects quite easily, e.g any string is, but to create a new type of these, you'd have to be able to define its internal methods.

Comment: An exotic object is basically any built-in that isn't a regular object. As the spec says, *"This specification defines several kinds of built-in exotic objects"*, and they are all listed right there, Array, String etc.

Comment: While I feel like this is an interesting question, I voted the question as too broad.  Beside the fact that you are asking essentially 5 different questions in one here, you are also essentially asking for people to re-interpret the language of the spec, which leads to translational inaccuracies.  This doesn't feel like a question that is reasonably scoped enough for this format.

Comment: @Claies: I partially agree with you... Is there any other StackExchange Q&A that might me more appropriate though? I believe that a question aimed at understanding an obscure part of one of the most popular programming languages belongs on one of the StackExchange Q&As, although maybe it should be presented in a different way (I wouldn't know how though)...

Comment: @peoro Have you asked the authors and maintainers of the specification publication for clarification as to what your specific questions are?

Comment: When in doubt, Quora.

Comment: I've written a [Medium post](https://medium.com/@li357/exotic-objects-in-ecmascript-2015-4fdbe3b8f0b8?source=linkShare-b3a9a4096d8d-1496640010) attempting to address all your questions. It's not my best work (did it all on my phone), but I wanted to answer a few questions you had.

Comment: I'm tempted to edit this down to one or two questions which would be reasonably answerable, but I'm not sure of the best way.  I'd suggest you think about doing so yourself.